# How do I fix disappearing div while scrolling?

Tags: html, css

The red element is disappearing while scrolling and I don't know what to do.
I am trying to do a custom scroll by element linked to parts of body.I don't know why this is happening. How do I fix it?

```css
html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 400%;

}

> This part of the code is working on a moving background stars

 @keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none;
}


.stars, .twinkling, .clouds {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:400vh;
  display:block;

}

.stars {
  background:#000 url(stars-bg.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:0;

}

.twinkling{
  background:transparent url(twinkling-bg.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:1;


  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 600s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 900s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 900s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 900s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 900s linear infinite;


}
**code of far right element**
.cont{
  height: 50%;
  width: 96.5%;
  float: left;
}
.conm{
  height: 50%;
  width: 3.5%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}
.point-tb{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6.5px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50%;
}
.scroll-1{
  height: 100px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #f00;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b5945c3b13.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="stars"></div>
<div class="twinkling">
<div class="cont"></div>
<div class="conm">
<div class="point-tb"></div>
<div class="scroll-1"></div>
</div>
</div>










</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red element is scrolling because of the following CSS properties.

```
html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 400%; /* This Here */
}
.stars, .twinkling, .clouds {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400vh; /* and this here */
  display: block;
}
```

Setting the `html` element to beyond `100%` `height` is considered bad practice. Remove the height attribute from each and this will fix your problem.

```
html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.stars, .twinkling, .clouds {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

**Why is this happening?** Most browsers by default will enable user scrolling whenever the HTML document extends passed `100%` of the height or `100%` the `width`. Since you are setting the `html` element and `.stars`, `.twinkling`, and `.clouds` to have a `height` value beyond 100%, the user can scroll down. When the user scrolls down the red element is moved up. **The red element never moves, the page does.**

If you attempting to create a custom slider I would wrap everything in a div, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="scrollbar">
        <!-- Scroll bar style elements. -->
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Content to be scrolled. -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then set the `.content` class to have a `height` property of beyond `100%`. Then you can use `JavaScript` to animate your scrollbar element based on content scrolling offset. This method will require `JavaScript` and use of the `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` CSS property. This essentially will attach the element to a particular area on the screen and prevent it from moving unless you tell it to. You will also need to use `overflow: hidden;` to disable the browsers auto scroll functionality for the content element. You can read more about the position property and overflow property here by w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp,
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

--

Alternatively, if you main goal is just to style a custom scrollbar, look into `::scrollbar` pseudo selector. You can read more about this here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

--

In addition to the element, use `/* Comment Here */` to insert CSS comments. Use `<!-- Comment Here -->` to insert HTML comments. I believe this was added after copying and pasting into stack overflow, but not using comments correctly can cause rendering issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use position:fixed in you css.